# Executing too commands withing the same loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of code:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = document.getElementById("myTbl").rows[i]; i++) {
    row.cells[headCatg.cellIndex].classList.remove("red");
    row.deleteCell(headCatg.cellIndex);
}
```

I need to remove the class "red" from each cell of the table column and then delete that column. The reason I need to remove class first, because it has been added to DOM by another cript and if I remove the column the class just appears in the next column.

When I run each of these commands (*remove()* and *deleteCell()*) individually in the loop, everything seem to work fine, but when I put them together, the column is removed but the class shifts to another column.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "put them together?" Deleting the cell should be sufficient without removing the class first. Please post your HTML structure so we can analyze.

Comment: this must have something to do with the other script. class don't "just appear" on other elements. The other script must be watching DOMNodeRemoved and applying the style then. knowing how that script works may be key.

Comment: Try iterating your list in reverse, otherwise you end up skipping elements because of the delete.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was calculating index withing the loop headCatg.cellIndex, so what I did I created a new var outside cellIndx = headCatg.cellIndex;  and then used it inside my loop row.deleteCell(cellIndx); It seems to be working fine now with just delete. Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the `HTMLcollection` to an array
The reason why your code wasn't working properly it's because HTMLcollection returns a live NodeList which means when you use remove on each element in the collection the other elements gets rearranged and the length of the list get's smaller causing you to skip some of them so you should convert your html collection to an array using `Array.from`

```
row = document.getElementByClassName("myTbl")
rowarr=Array.from(row)


for (var i = 0,  rowarr.length; i++) {
    row[i].cells[headCatg.cellIndex].classList.remove("red");
    row[i].deleteCell(headCatg.cellIndex);
}
```

Comment: but he wasn't removing any rows. He's removing cells from the row, so this wouldn't matter. Also, this code doesn't work for a couple reasons ("row" is not an array, you don't access the copy, missing a section on the for loop)